# save html/php code in variable

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables, pdf

I already tried to get the content of a url into a variable and send it to a php file (to get the content with file_get_contents ()) and print it to a pdf. Every time the variable sends the url to the php file, the content will be just reloaded. As I want to manipulate the html content before, its not the solution I am searching for.

How can I get the html content (which will be converted out of the php code down here) in a variable, to send it (without reloading) to the php file? They are dynamically created images which I want to change and delete individually and then send the content to a php file.

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_parent' => $post->ID,  'orderby' =>     'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC'); 
            $attachments = get_children($args); 
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
//use $attachment->ID to retrieve attachment information
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
$img = '<img class="print-no" src="'.$image[0].'" />';


   echo '<span class="print-no">';

            echo $img;

                 echo '</span>'; 
}
?>
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you talking about AJAX?? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: I dont know if it needs AJAX for this. I "just" have this php file with the generated images. And the php file with the code to create a pdf. I want to get some content (the php code part above) of the html (when clicked) transfered to the php file to create the pdf out of it.

Comment: Yea, you need Ajax for that if you dont' want to reload your page

Comment: Ya but I dont want to load a whole php page. I want to get a part of the html stored in a variable and send it to another php file to work with it. any suggestions for that? or if it only works with ajax...a tip to start with?

Comment: ajax is what @joren is saying. ajax is what you need if you dont want to reload whole page. ajax ajax :). or you could use $_SESSION but things will expire so that might annoy users

Comment: actually $_SESSION is more what I am searching for. Any help how it could be used with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can save the elements in a variable and print it later.

```
$me ='<span class="print-no">';

       $me.= $img;

             $me.= '</span>';
```